# Detect all browsers except IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, .htaccess, redirect

Is there a way to detect all browsers but IE for a redirect with either HTAccess or Javascript? Something like if not IE, redirect to site.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using IE's *conditional comments* rather since that would mean that the redirect code will not be even interpreted by IE. i.e. IE wont have *run* the JS code at all, only other browsers will.

**Redirection using JS**

```
<!--[if !IE]> -->
    <script>
    window.location.href = 'http://not-ie.com'
    </script>
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

**Redirection using meta refresh**

```
<!--[if !IE]> -->
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=http://not-ie.com/"> 
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

**Technique for *not showing the page* before redirection**

You can do this by rendering the `<body>` tag conditionally. *Disclaimer*: haven't tested this.

```
<!-- for non-ie browsers, render the body tag as invisible -->
<!--[if !IE]> -->
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=http://not-ie.com/"> 
    <body style="display: none">
<!-- <![endif]-->

<!-- for ie, render the body tag normally -->
<!--[if IE]> -->
    <body>
<!-- <![endif]-->

<!-- your page content HTML goes here -->

</body></html>
```

For more info on *conditional comments*: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Comment: very nice, in your code you can also use meta-redirect which work even IE have javascript disabled.

Comment: Absolutely, you can put any valid HTML like meta, base (if you have a different resource location for IE etc.) or anything else inside the condition.

Comment: Essentially what I'm trying to do is redirect when someone is visiting an IE only page with a browser that is not IE. This works actually quite well. Thanks.

Comment: Have updated the answer with info on how this can be done via meta refresh. Change **5** as needed - this is the number of seconds the browser will *wait* before redirecting.

Comment: The meta refresh is too slow. Even when setting it to 0, the user can still see the page which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Without JS it may be difficult to solve the last problem (page showing up before redirect).. Let me think..

Comment: Your javascript worked great and that is what I intend to use. Thanks, again.

Comment: Cool. Glad you got it working. Just a suggestion - its always better to assume that the user may just have JS disabled.

Answer (score 2):

```
var ie = /msie/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
if (!ie) { location.href = 'http://site.com'; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
<!--[if IE 6]><script>location.href='youhazie6.htm';</script><![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

**You do understand that method with conditional comments, described in the previous unswer won't work in IE10?** IE10 doesn't support conditional comments and it releases soon.

So, to make your code really work, rely either on feature detection or on userAgent.
But userAgent also fails sometime, when there are many plugins, so "Internet Explorer" or "MSIE" may be cut in real life.

To make the detection more reliable, throw in a bit of feature sniffing:

```
if ('\v'=='v' || /msie/i.test(navigator.userAgent);) {
  // ah that's you IE!
}
```

That's enough.

Comment: IE9 and IE10 will not see that page. IE8 and below will.